# What is the most Inputs on An analog Pin with a specified Accuracy on the Resistors Used?

Tags: electronics, resistor

I am asking about the technique were switches and resistors in series are used on the analog pin, so it creates a voltage divider when one of the switches is pressed, it a well known technique it is described here with 5 buttons on one analog pin

http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-access-5-buttons-through-1-Arduino-input/

Obviously we assume the circuit is set up correctly e.g. the voltage reference is stable-but such things aren't the main point of this question.
My question is about an obvious generalisation of that circuit for more inputs - and where the resistors are all replaced by, a single type of resistor, a fixed resistance value (e.g. 4k ohm) with a known error on the resistance (e.g. 5%). We use the 4k resistors to make up larger values 4k,8k,12k,16k,20k Ohms and make the 100k Ohm resistor out of twenty five 4k ohm resistors.
My question using only 4k ohm resistors (connected in series in the voltage divider) within a 5% error of their value -what is the most switches  we can theoretically connect for reliable working on one analog pin?-I'll have a guess at 20 switches.

The second question is given X ohm resistors (connected in series in the voltage divider) within a E% error of their value -what is the most switches, M,  we can theoretically connect for reliable working on one analog pin? So there will be a formula for this-so what is it?

Comment: Looks like a school assignment ...

Comment: As some point even with perfect resistors you will run into noise, impact of dirty contacts, etc...  It's not clear that what precision resistors will gain you over loose tolerance ones would leave enough margin for these concerns, though the situation might be better than pushing the limits of these concerns on top of only approximate resistances.

Comment: @LookAlterno Its not a school assignment

Comment: @LookAlterno I just wan't to know a formula,or a proof, for the most number of
inputs I can use reliably,as that means I can _replicate_ the circuit reliably,on the arduino with certain resistors
as that would be the cheapest way for me to do the
input of my circuit.

Answer (score 1):

> My question using only 4k ohm resistors (connected in series in the
>   voltage divider)

The circuit you are describing (a collection of identical resistors
connected in series) is quite different from the one discussed in the
link you provide. I assume you have in mind something analogous to a
digital pot, i.e. a chain of N resistors between GND and Vcc, with N
switches connecting the Arduino analog input to N taps along the chain:
N−1 taps in between consecutive resistors and one extra tap at GND¹.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7ML62.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The push buttons could actually be the multiple contacts of a rotary
switch. If using real push buttons, it would be tricky to know whether a
button is being pushed or if you are just reading noise, though it can
be known by toggling the pin between output and input and using its
stray capacitance.

In this case, the worst case error happens when all the resistors on one
side of the tap are 5% too high, while all those at the other side are
5% too low. It can be easily shown that the minimum possible voltage at
tap k is

V<sub>−</sub>(k) = k(1−e)/(k(1−e) + (N−k)(1+e))×Vcc

where e = 0.05 is the 5% tolerance of the resistors. The
maximum possible voltage, V<sub>+</sub>(k), is given by the same formula
after replacing e by −e.

The graph below shows the expected voltage at each tap for a chain of
20 resistors, with the error bars showing the possible voltage
ranges. The blue curves are the analytical expressions of
V<sub>−</sub>(k) and V<sub>+</sub>(k).

[image]

As can be seen on the graph, the largest error bars are the ones closer
to the central tap. Thus, the buttons can be discriminated accurately if
the two taps closest to the center have non overlapping error bars. This
criterion could be translated into an exact formula, but the formula
would be quite complex and depend on the parity of N. I propose to do
instead some approximations, starting with a first order Taylor
expansion on the error. This expansion gives the length of the error
bars as

V<sub>+</sub>(k) − V<sub>−</sub>(k) ≈ 4/N<sup>2</sup> k (N−k) e × Vcc

This error is maximal when k = N/2 (we will forget the parity issue):

V<sub>+</sub>(N/2) − V<sub>−</sub>(N/2k) ≈ e × Vcc

Then we say that the taps can be discriminated if this error is smaller
than the expected voltage difference between consecutive taps, namely
Vcc/N. Then the criterion is now simply

N ≤ 1/e

which is exactly what your intuition told you.

---

¹ The extra tap could be at Vcc rather than GND. It would be unwise,
however, to tap *both* GND and Vcc, as a user pressing both buttons
simultaneously would then short the power supply.

---

**Edit** to answer the questions in comments.

Yes, you could use the expressions of V<sub>+</sub> and V<sub>−</sub> to
set the thresholds for discriminating the buttons. For example, you
could set the threshold between k and k+1 halfway between
V<sub>+</sub>(k) and V<sub>−</sub>(k+1), i.e.

threshold(k, k+1) = (V<sub>+</sub>(k) + V<sub>−</sub>(k+1)) / 2

However, if you try to compute that, you will see that it is extremely
close the average between the expected voltages. Then, you could use
that average as your threshold, which is given by a very simple formula:

threshold(k, k+1) = (k+½)/N×Vcc

Then, the pin number is just the integer closest to V<sub>in</sub>/Vcc×N.
Assuming N = 20, this can be written as:

```c++
const float VCC = 5.0
float voltage = analogRead(PIN) * VCC / 1024;
int button_number = round(voltage / VCC * 20);
```

This can be optimized to use only integer arithmetics:

```c++
int button_number = (analogRead(PIN) * 5 + 128) >> 8;
```

Note that 20 buttons is kind of borderline. Your system could fail
if the errors due to resistor inaccuracies and those intrinsic to the
ADC (offset, gain error...) add up the wrong way. If you are building
only one device, then the safest fix would be to take note of the value
`analogRead()` returns for each button, and set the thresholds halfway
between consecutive values.

You could also measure the resistances of all your resistors, and
arrange them in a way that minimizes the errors. For example, if you
number the resistors from 0 to 19 in order of increasing resistance, I
would build the chain by arranging them in the following order:

0 19 2 17 4 15 6 13 8 11 9 10 7 12 5 14 3 16 1 18

Then you could most likely use the simple formula above to get the
button number at a minimal computing cost.

Comment: Yes-you are correct -that is the circuit I had in mind.

Comment: Im asking this question because I have a lot of cheap
resistors with the same value and wanted to know what
the most inputs I can get from 1 pin.

Comment: So If I chose N=20 resistors, then I could directly use 
the analytical expressions of V−(k) and V+(k) to set the
bounds voltage tap k will produce in my arduino sketch?-
 -is that correct?

Comment: And we dont use tap 20 in practice because V−(20)=V−(20)
i.e. there are no lower and upper bounds

Comment: This is the sort of answer I had in mind when I [wrote this Meta post](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2524/how-to-write-a-good-answer-for-arduino-stack-exchange).

Comment: "Your system could fail if the errors due to resistor inaccuracies and those intrinsic to the ADC (offset, gain error...) add up the wrong way. If you are building only one device, then the safest fix would be to take note of the value"

Comment: So if you wanted the safest provable way without measuring any voltages (e.g. for building lots of devices quickly) then you can use tap all the odd taps
as input buttons 1,3,5,...,19 and the theoretical thresholds for would be 
 V+(k-1)< V(k) < V-(k+1) , for the voltage V(k) from tap (odd numbered) k.

Comment: This would give you 9 buttons you can use without the need to know
the actual voltages-measured in some way -it only depends on the
known errors of the known components involved.

Comment: So you get theoretically provable lower and upper voltage thresholds, for
each of the  at the cost of using 11 less buttons-you could think of it
as- to make error bounds theoretically computable-without measurement
of some sort-costs 11 resistors.

Comment: Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

The same the same technique is used routinely for 4x4 keypads. You don't really need very precise resistor as long as the final divider produce final voltage that are differente enough.

For each button/key you need to reserve some voltage range for it.
You can expected some random fluctuation every time you read the analog input, so you need some safety margin.

I think you can use up to 32 button/key using this technique. That's give you 150 mV of distance between each button (or +/- 32 for the corresponding analog value.

Comment: I would like an answer with a mathematical formula,that
is more enlightening for me and will give me a better
understanding.

Comment: And a formula would prove it can be replicated because
its like a proof of reliability

Comment: A possible error in your answer is -because you are not being 
precise  it may mean that the circuit can't be reliably
replicated (because it may just depend on those specific
resistors used.)

Answer (score 0):

You're just making a voltage resistor divider, with Vin at the top of the string of resistors, Vout at the selected resistor junction, and Gnd at the bottom.
Using 5V as Vin, then

Vout = Vin x (sum of resistance below the junction)/(sum of the entire string).

For example, 10 1K resistors, and the junction is between resistors 5 and 6 (resistor 1, R1, connected to Vin, resistor 10, R10, to Gnd).

Vout = 5V * 5,000/(10,000) = 2.5V

Arduino will return a reading of ~ 2.5V/5V * 1024 = 512 (~4.88mV per step)

Connect between R7 and R8

Vout = 5V * 3,000/(10,000) = 1.5V

analogRead = ~1.5/5 * 1024 = 307